# Call a function upon python logger entry being created

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have a client which sends requests to a rest api. The client is already in production and written in a way that catches all sorts of exceptions that could potentially occur. I want to make an addition so that whenever an exception message is logged, a function is called that takes this exception message alongside the stacktrace and sends it to a specified email address. My first attempt was to initiate the logger as following:

```
self.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
self.log.exception = MagicMock(side_effect=self.log.exception)
```

and to then check whether log.exception has been called or not. This approach however doesn't give me access to the log message nor the stacktrace. Is there an easier way to accomplish this than to extend the entire logging module?

Comment: Sounds like you just want to add another handler to the existing logger.

Answer (score 2):

If `MagicMock` is a logger object and implement all required methods (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) you can add use the following:

```
fh = MagicMock()
fh.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an [`SMTPHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#logging.handlers.SMTPHandler) to the logger.

```
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler


self.log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
send_email = SMTPHandler(...)
self.log.addHandler(send_email)
```

See the documentation for details on how to configure the handler. To customize the email, subclass `SMTPHandler` and override the `emit` method.